# Who was Maurice Fischer in the third-level dream?

Tags: inception

In the first level of the dream, Eames was able to impersonate Browning.
In the second level of dream (@ the lobby), Eames also impersonated the beautiful woman and stole Fischer's wallet.

But I just don't understand who was Maurice Fischer in the third level of the dream because Eames was outside the room.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can be reasonably certain that the elder Fischer was simply a construct of the third-level dream maze created by Ariadne, essentially the prize at the centre. None of the other character actors are available to play him and he's already *locked inside* the hospital/vault when Fischer Jr and Eames arrive at the tower.

We know from the persistent presence of Mal, courtesy of Cobb's mucked up psyche, that as well as creating physical locations and obstacles such as guards, it's perfectly possible to create projected characters, something that's backed up by this deleted scene from the screenplay (during the '*planning the heist*' scene)

> Two AFRICAN PEDESTRIANS wander into view.
>
> **ARTHUR:** *Are those yours?*
>
> Eames shakes his head. Cobb turns to Yusuf.
>
> **ARTHUR:** *Yusuf?*
>
> **YUSUF**: *Yup. Sorry.*
>
> **COBB:** *Suppress them. We don’t bring our own projections into the dream—we let Fischer’s subconscious supply the people.*

Comment: While the general reasoning is sound, I would go a step further and say it is possibly young Fisher's own projection. Or a bit of both, Ariadne bringing Maurice in and Fisher filling out the details of his behaviour. Remember the scene earlier when they meet Browing in the hotel and Eames notes that it is Fisher's own emanation of Browing, signaling his growing distrust of him. In the same way it was probably vital that Fisher develops his dream father's behaviour on his own as part of the inception stemming from his very own mind.